# Restore memory dump

Tags: debugging, memory-dump

If in testing on a computer without a debugger, say a client's computer, I encounter a bug that may have corrupted the state of the program but not actually crashed it, I know I can take a memory dump using the Windows Task Manager (right click on process name, create dump file).

I can use these with WinDbg to peek around in memory, etc., but what would be most useful to me is to be able to restore the dump into memory so that I can continue interacting with the program. Is this possible? If so, how? Is there a tool that can restore it or do I need to write my own.

Comment: @m0skit0 I updated my question. Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: I don't know for Windows, which is what you seem you're using. For Linux, [check this](http://lwn.net/Articles/342819/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical usermode dumps or minidumps do not contain enough information to do so. While they contain all usermode memory, they do not contain kernel memory, so open handles to kernel resources like files or network sockets will not be included in the dump (and even if they were, the hard disk has most likely changed so just trying to write to the hard disk may corrupt your system even more).

The only way I see to restore a memory dump is restoring the full memory and all other state like hard disk state, which can be done with most virtual machine software (which will, however, disconnect all your network connections on restore; gratefully most programs can handle lost network connectsions better than lost file handles).

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I could do this with Hyper-V snapshots. If I run my program in a virtual machine, I can optionally dump the memory, create a snapshot, transfer the dump if necessary, come back some time later, restore the snapshot and continue the program.